# UIProgressView loading bar with percentage

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swift3, uiprogressview

I want to make a loading bar in Swift 3 for my iOS project. I'm doing a web view for the moment and need to do this loading bar to show in between the actions. I know it is fake loading bar and I saw code in Objective-C and tried to make something out of it in Swift but I'm afraid that my logic is wrong, since I'm new in Swift.

The problem I'm having is that I don't acctually know if I set vars `theBool` and `timer` to the right place and I dont know how to use `Timer()`.

And to tell you what I see when I run the app, Progress bar is showing the whole time, but it's not loading.

This is my code so far

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var theBool = false
    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        progressView.progress = 0.0

        //Reading the webview
        let websiteURL = URL(string: "http://google.com")
        let websiteURLRequest = URLRequest(url: websiteURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(websiteURLRequest)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad (){
        if webView.isLoading == true {
        theBool = true
        }
    }

    func handleProgress () {
        if (theBool){
            if (progressView.progress >= 1) {
                progressView.isHidden = true
                timer.invalidate()
            } else {
                progressView.progress += 0.1
            }
        } else {
            progressView.progress += 0.05
            if (progressView.progress >= 0.95) {
                progressView.progress = 0.95
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    func addValsToProgress () ->String {
        if (webViewLoading() == true) {
            view.progressView.setProgre
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you actually handle the progress change, like a download progress handler. Are you just doing this as a dummy process?

Comment: If all you want to do is start a timer to call that dummy method, you should say `yourTimerName = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: I've read about loading bars and found out that all of those loading bars are actually fake and there was some code in objective-c on how to make that progress bar which loads till 95% then stops and waits for the page to load. when the page loads it fills the last 5% very fast and then shows the page.
That's what I want, except if you know a way to get the process time when I tap on something and calculate remaining time of the load and display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a few tries with the solutions you posted, I found an answer.
It's so simple that I was ashamed.

It works like a charm. Thank you all for your answers :)

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    webView.delegate=self
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(0.1, animated: false)
}


func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {

    self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: And it shows a changing Progress while a Long loading? Or only at the when it finished?

Comment: It is a "Fake" Progress with an Animation to 1 on finished load?

Comment: But sometimes it is enough only to have something to entertain the user and there is not the need of real progress data. Thumbs up for this easy solution. Thx for sharing :)

Comment: I wanted to do it the proper way, but cant find a way to get the predicted time to finish the process. I've read about how to do it and found out that people actually fake it with this method or some other methods similar to this one. I've even tried to implement them but since they are for older versions of swift or for objective c, I couldn't make any of them work except this one.

I'm also a bit disappointed that the right way to do this is so hard to find :/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code that you provided, you need to initialize the `timer` with a time interval and an action. That way when the timer is invoked, it calls `handleProgress`. The timer should `fire` when the loading state begins and will periodically call `handleProgress` until loading has finished. At that point, the timer will be `invalidated` and will stop calling `handleProgress`.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer for how to do that.

Comment: so I called Timer that calls handleProgress and nothing happens.
am I not firing the timer on correct way?

Comment: found a solution, posted it. thank you for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a fake loading bar. you can get it work with `WKWebView`

#### KVO Observer

you can place a KVO observer to this value:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415007-estimatedprogress

YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vd3Imcc7ctw

one older example here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-monitor-wkwebview-page-load-progress-using-key-value-observing

more examples on github search: https://github.com/search?l=Swift&o=desc&q=estimatedProgress+addObserver&s=indexed&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

#### Delegates

WKNavigationDelegate

https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate

also there are some delegate callbacks here:

> optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
>               didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)

see https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview

PS: there is also WKUIDelegate - but there are not so interesting methods

https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkuidelegate

Comment: did what you wrote here and view is showing me the loading bar, but it's not loading anything.

switched to WKWebView and everything

Comment: found a solution, posted it. thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Ok. Mhh. It should be loading ;)

Comment: Maybe it is more difficult to implement or the examples are out of date :(

Comment: just out of curiosity, "progressView.sizeToFit()" stops my app, how do you handle this problem?

Comment: i have no clue :(

Comment: feel free to post a new question with you current full code :)

Comment: I'm stubborn so I'll figure it out and let you know ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134511/discussion-between-matej-maric-and-muescha).